# Delete specific line from hosts

Tags: bash, sed

I want to delete specific line from `hosts` file in my home dir:

```
~$ echo "193.10.1.1 localhost" >> hosts
~$ echo "127.0.0.1 localhost" >> hosts
~$ cat hosts
193.10.1.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost
~$ sed '/127.0.0.1/d' hosts > hosts
~$ cat hosts
```

But file is emtpy. How do I delete mactching line and then print result back in file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file is truncated when you redirect output using `>`, before the `sed` command actually runs.

#### BSD `sed`

Use `sed -i .bak '/^127\.0\.0\.1[[:space:]]/d' hosts` instead to edit a file inline, saving a backup with the `bak` extension, or `sed -i '' [...]` to skip backup creation.

#### GNU `sed`

Use `sed -ibak '/^127\.0\.0\.1[[:space:]]/d' hosts` instead to edit a file inline, saving a backup with the `bak` extension, or `sed -i [...]` to skip backup creation.

---

You can also do this manually, e.g. the following:

```
sed '/^127\.0\.0\.1[[:space:]]/d' hosts > hosts.new
cat hosts.new > hosts
rm hosts.new
```

While this is one more line that `mv hosts.new hosts`, it'll retain the file metadata of `hosts`.

Comment: @Mighter You might have a different sed. Skip the argument to `-i`, i.e.  `sed -i '/127.0.0.1/d' hosts`